# What should I do for me to paste the photo using asset in <img src=" ? ">

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

```
        @foreach ($profiles as $profile)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $profile->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $profile->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $profile->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $profile->age }}</td>
            <td>{{ $profile->gender }}</td>
            <td>{{ $profile->position }}</td>
            <td>{{ $profile->department }}</td>
            <td>{{ $profile->phone_number }}</td>
            <td>
                @if ($profile->images)
   **             <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/'.$profile->images) }}" alt="Profile Image"
                    style="max-width: 50px; border-radius: 50%;">**
                @else
                No Image
                @endif
            </td>
```

I already try using URL in asset, but it didn't work at all, I already make the storage folder short but it didn't help me at all.

Comment: Did you check that the src="" actually contains the correct path? Also check what `$profile->images` contains, make sure your variables contain the data you expect

Comment: yes I already check it many times and the $profile->images is the URL came from my database

Comment: Are you sure that the `images` field of the `$profile` object in `$profile->images` returns a URL? I thought it was an affair because of the field name. Are you in a relationship?

Comment: Have you created symbolic link to storage directory in public? You can do this by running `php artisan storage:link`. You can find more info on this here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk.

Comment: @vstruhar fyi OP is using laravel 8 or at least tagged it.

Comment: you should include what the value of `{{ asset('storage/app/public/'.$profile->images) }}` and the expected url that you know works.

Comment: we can't just guess what those values are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are linking it correctly with asset and prefix. try

It will look for an image inside of a public/storage folder where you can define your own image folder

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($pathToImage) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below steps:

1. Try save image location absolute instead of relative URL location in this case you should just put image URL location directive

   ```
   <img src="{{$profile->images}}" alt="Profile Image" style="max-width: 50px; border-radius: 50%;">
   ```
2. If you want to save location in relative mode first of all check storage connect to your project or not

In laravel you can use:

> php artisan storage:link

In Linux you can use:

> ln -s /storagelocation public/storage

And then use your code to show the img

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/'.$profile->images) }}"Alt="Profile Image" style="max-width: 50px; border-radius: 50%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check these things:

1. Check your `.env` file and `APP_URL` value: it should be `https://[yourwebsite.com]` - some people forget to change it from the default `localhost` or provide incorrect URL with an extra folder/subdomain
2. If you store images in `storage/app/public`, check if you have run `php artisan storage:link` **successfully** (so, no errors happened) to create the symlink.
3. Check if your web-server root folder is successfully pointed to the `/public` folder of the Laravel project.
4. Then, you can call those `storage/app/public` images with `asset('storage/'.$profile->images)`

Check the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

By the way, I would rename the variable from `images` to `image`, as it seems to be a single image and would likely be misunderstood by future developers.